# Calling Function from Nodejs at Client side: require is not defined

Tags: node.js, json, server, client, svelte

I understood that there are a few similar questions asking about this. However, I do not find a solution to my problem. I am using svelte and nodejs from my project. I am fetching JSON file from the server-side and wanted to call the function on the client-side using require. Below is my code on the server-side.

DataService.js

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

let data;
;(async ()=>{
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/tables.json');
    data = await res.json();
    // console.log(data);
})()

export const getTable = () => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
    // console.log(data);
}
```

When I tried to call getTable() from the client-side, an error says "require is not defined".I understood from various answers that require is only for server-side and not client-side. Some solutions mentioned that I used consider using, Script, commonjs, browersify and more.

Here is my client-side code.

Catalog.svelte

```
<script >
import {getTable} from '../components/dataservice.js';

console.log(getTable()); //gives an error of require is not defined


</script>

<h1>Table</h1>
```

If I remove "const fetch = require('node-fetch')" from Dataservice.js, it gives me undefined and fetch is not defined.

Any help would be appreciated as I have struggled to resolve this for days.

Comment: You can't run Node.js on the client. You should write your DataService.js as a client script OR as a server script and query information between

Comment: Do you use a bundler like Webpack, rollup or parcel?

Comment: i have rollup in my svelte project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```js
const fetch = typeof window !== 'undefined'
  ? window.fetch
  : require('node-fetch');
```

Comment: wow it works! thanks! just checking if this works for other require method? For example const uniqBy = require('lodash.uniqby');   change it to like const uniqBy = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.uniqBy : require('lodash.uniqby') ?

Comment: No. It works because `fetch` already exists in a browser context; `uniqBy` doesn't. In general you should use `import` (and if you wanted to do so here you could use an isomorphic fetch library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-unfetch)